# Azure Data Flow How to get Max id and return only that row which has max id

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to filer max id and return the last row in the Azure Data flow. Or use Filter in data flow and get only last max id.

[image]
In SQL we Get do it like this

```
  SELECT Level1Id FROM  [D].[DepartmentGroupLevel1]
WHERE [Level1Id] = (SELECT MAX([Level1Id]) FROM [D].[DepartmentGroupLevel1])
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to that?

Answer (score 1):

It should just be an Aggregate without any group-by. Group by is optional in the Agg transformation.